# Fluid grid with CSS - Not fluid

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, grid-layout

I am trying to make my own fluid grid with a `max-width: 1280px`and a `min-width: 950px`.

Here is what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/dmL7A/

and here is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/GaFYQ/

The content won't scale down proportional in my example.
Instead the grids will go below each other when the window is scaled down.

Has someone tried this before if YES, what was the solution?

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    min-width: 950px;
    background:#999999; 
}

.container {
    margin: 0 -0.915% 10px !important;
}

.col {
    margin:0 0.75%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    max-height: 320px
}

.container .col img {
    width: 100%;
}

.grid2 {
    width:18,75%;
}

.grid4 {
    width:39,1%;
}

.grid6 {
    width:60%;
}

.grid8 {
    width:80%;
}

.grid10 {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: `css` uses `.` not `,` as decimal delimeter's :) your `.grid4` and `.grid2` styles need to be updated

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest setting the margin to .col to 0. Having a marging of 0.75% will give you varying margins depending on the width of the column.

Change your column sizes to:

```
 .grid2 {
    width:20%;
}

.grid4 {
    width:40%;
}

.grid6 {
    width:60%;
}

.grid8 {
    width:80%;
}

.grid10 {
    width:100%;
}
```

To give a bit of spacing between your columns, add the following to your .col class

```
.col {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     padding:0 10px;
}
```

Setting box-sizing: border-box; will mean any padding your give to your element will not effect the width.

Comment: To have it fluid can the width then be exactly ex. 20%?

Answer (score 0):

CSS uses `.` not `,` as decimal delimeters; your `.grid4` and `.grid2` styles need to be updated.

I would also recommend using a `clearfix` solution to give your `.container` element back its height (http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
.cf{
    *zoom:1;
}
```

Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GaFYQ/4/

However, if you are looking for a great 'out-of-the-box' grid system I would recommend having a look at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and their [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Comment: The Bootstrap grid system, is to much code for my taste.
I like a simple code, and as far as I can see it is now set up for five columns as I use.

Comment: No problem, for future reference there is a customise section on their site that will let you change the number of columns (e.g. to 10) http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system